# Add Classes On TextBox foucusout event via jQuery

Tags: javascript

Hi I am succeeded to remove classes on edit button click, but I am having an issue to adding classes back.

Here is the code given below.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".edit").click(function() {

    $(this).parent().find('.edit-field-area').removeClass('edit-field-area');
    $(this).removeClass('edit-button');
    $(this).parent().find('.transparent-control').prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).parent().find('.transparent-control').focus();
  });

  $(".transparent-control").focusout(function() {
    debugger;
    $(this).parent().find('.row').find('.edit').addClass('edit-button');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="Images/side-border.png" width="100" height="20" />
    <img src="http://localhost:49606/img/Thumbnail5.jpg" class="img-circle" width="100" height="100" alt="Muhammad Essa" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 edit-field-area heading-one">
        <input type="text" id="name" disabled="disabled" class="transparent-control" value="Muhammad Essa Rind" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 edit-button heading-one edit" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 9px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 edit-field-area">
        <input type="text" id="job" class="transparent-control" value="Software Developer at United Marine Agencies PVT LTD" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 edit-button edit" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 edit-field-area">
        <input type="text" id="country" class="transparent-control" value="Pakistan" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 edit-button edit" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <h6><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple idea about the adding class on textbox focus out is in this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8hkha5b0/1/), Please click to see

```
Replace 
$(this).parent().find('.row').find('.edit').addClass('edit-button');
With 
            $(this).addClass('edit-button');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(".transparent-control").onblur(function () {
        debugger;
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.edit').addClass('edit-button');
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);

});
```

**onblur** event is triggered when input loses focus.